# Browser independent javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Why is the behaviour of this code different in each browser? What should I change to accomplish the same behaviour in all of them? In Firefox it is fine, it uses the url `/some/path/?searchedText=sometext`, in IE it does nothing when I click on `inputButton` and in Chrome it fails because it encodes `?` like this: `/some/path/%3FsearchedText=sometext` instead of the `/some/path/?searchedText=sometext`

html

`<input id="inputText" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Searched text">
 <input id="inputButton" type='button' value='Search' class="btn" onclick="myFunction()"/>`

javascript

```
function myFunction() {
var text = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
var location = "some/path/?searchedText=";
window.location.pathname = location + text;
}
```

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: It is the newest version 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `window.location.pathname` which is great way to avoid explicity passing the starting (http://www.something.com) hostname but it also treats query string as path and therefore encodes them you can avoid that by manully constructing each url component and then use `window.location.href`

```
function myFunction() {
  var text = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  var protocol = window.location.protocol;
  var hostname = window.location.hostname;
  var url = protocol + '//' + hostname + "/some/path?searchedText=" + text;
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the property [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location#Example_5_Send_a_string_of_data_to_the_server_by_modifying_the_search_property).

```
window.location.search = '?searchedText=' + text;
```